# Ошибка в fetch() при попытке взять данные с сервера

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch, type-error

```
     Код fetch-запроса в js

async auth() {
                this.isLoaing = true
                async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
                    // Default options are marked with *
                    const response = await fetch(url, {
                        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
                        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
                        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
                        body: JSON.stringify(data)
                    })
                    return await response.json()
                }
                postData(this.API_URL, { userLogin: this.userLogin, userPassword: this.userPassword })
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log(data);
                    });
            }

    Обработчик в PHP

function checkAuth() {
    $body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $stmt = pdo()->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userLogin` = :userLogin');
    $stmt->execute([
        'userLogin' => $body['userLogin'],
    ]);
    if(!$stmt->rowCount()){
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Authorisation error');
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));
    } else{
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *'); 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');    
    $json = json_encode($user, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    echo $json;
    }
    switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo 'Ошибок нет';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo 'Достигнута максимальная глубина стека';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo 'Некорректные разряды или несоответствие режимов';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo 'Некорректный управляющий символ';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo 'Синтаксическая ошибка, некорректный JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo 'Некорректные символы UTF-8, возможно неверно закодирован';
        break;
        default:
            echo 'Неизвестная ошибка';
        break;
    } 
}
```

Причем в Postman данные отправляются нормально и status: 200. Подскажите, что делать, я уже замучался

Ошибки:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://anteiserver:8080/api/core/function.php' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
        
        
POST http://anteiserver:8080/api/core/function.php net::ERR_FAILED
postData @ AuthForm.vue:27
auth @ AuthForm.vue:41
(анонимный) @ AuthForm.vue:56
(анонимный) @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1483
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:173
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:182
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:345
                        
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at postData (AuthForm.vue:27:40)
    at Proxy.auth (AuthForm.vue:41:13)
    at AuthForm.vue:56:63
    at runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1483:16
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:173:22)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:182:21)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:345:9)
```

[image: Консоль ошибок]

[image: Запрос в Postman]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Все header'ы должны стоять перед echo, а не в конце

Comment: Поправил header'ы, дело не изменилось, ошибки такие же

Comment: +`ssl`? без `https` сплошная боль..

Comment: Обновите код как поправили

Comment: Я просто делаю на Localhost всё, в целом в этом новичок

Comment: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check` — посмотрите в браузерном мониторинге сети, что там за preflight request такой, и исправьте php-код так, чтобы он на него отвечал что-нибудь внятное

Comment: Впрочем, если на скриншотах и есть этот самый preflight request, то информации как-то негусто... Ну попробую предположить, что браузер отправляет OPTIONS-запрос, а ваш php-код должен отправить на него пустой ответ с правильными заголовками

Comment: А разве не POST отправляется?

Comment: Перед POST-запросом браузер отправляет специальный OPTIONS-запрос, чтобы по ответу на него определить, есть ли у браузера право отправить POST-запрос. И если такое право есть, то php-код должен ответить на OPTIONS-запрос со всеми нужными заголовками

Comment: Не понимаю как это реализовать, если честно, для меня это темный лес

Comment: А вообще, если я правильно понимаю, причиной возникновения OPTIONS-запроса является использование `Content-Type: application/json` в запросе — такое значение Content-Type не считается «простым» и браузер проверяет наличие права на его использование путём отправки OPTIONS-запроса. Если вы избавитесь от json-запроса, заменив json на url-кодирование и заголовок `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (который считается «простым»), то, возможно, OPTIONS-запрос исчезнет и браузер будет отправлять сразу POST-запрос

Comment: Обо всём этом есть в документации (правда, на английском) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: С url-кодированием никогда не работал, в целом можно попробовать, также могу дать Вам ссылку на live share, но это если, конечно, не лень и не заняты

Comment: [Handling CORS requests properly is a tad more involved. Here is a function that will respond more fully (and properly).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/12593651) используйте функцию, echo уберите только.